# Development with a tablet, not a mouse

Tags: ergonomics

Lifehacker had a post a couple days ago asking people about [the best mouse you've ever had](http://lifehacker.com/5054519/) and it appears some people have traded their mouse for a tablet.

I'm curious if anyone here has traded their mouse in for a tablet?  Does it work well for development?  Looking for pros and cons from people who have tried it or are using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a small Wacom tablet as my primary "mouse" for a couple years. I found the tablet to be very natural, and even got used to typing while holding the stylus in between my fingers. (I don't type the "correct fingers on home row" way anyway, so it wasn't that big of an adjustment)

I did find that I got MUCH better at using the keyboard for most navigation because when I did put down the stylus, I didn't want to have to pick it back up.

Since I had a cheaper tablet, after a couple years of use the protective plastic had a gridwork of scratches that made it sometime more difficult for precise mouse movements (being a web-developer, I've done my share of quick graphic design pieces).  Eventually, it got to a point where I needed to replace it and rather than spending the money on a new tablet, I bought a new optical mouse because was heavily into Counterstrike at the time and couldn't justify buying an input that only benefit one of my obsessions.

Overall, I didn't really notice any great benefits or drawbacks.. it was simply just a different way to use the computer.

To the critcism clicking buttons on a tablet.. the stylus I used had a click/right-click built right into it.  No searching for anything..

Answer (score 1):

For development, I tend to switch between the keyboard for typing and shortcuts, and the mouse for pointing at things. Given that context:

I've heard no end of praise for this approach from everyone who's used it. They say it's easier on the wrist, it feels more natural, and once you're used to it, it's impossible to go back without missing it. Strong enough praise that I'm planning on switching within the next two paycheques.

Answer (score 1):

I second what Dan Udey says.  I had no trouble switching to a tablet and on the rare occasions that I use a pointer at all while programming, it is a blessing.  One simple example: scrolling through a long list by dragging the scrollbar seems more natural with a tablet than a mouse.

And as an added benefit, when I am in "graphic artist" mode on little projects the tablet is an obvious win.

Spodi: I agree on the keyboard for shortcuts, so the only buttons I use on either the mouse or the tablet are the first and second, both of which are available on the pen; I am not sure what you mean by looking at the tablet to click buttons.  As for the speed of getting to the mouse, I tuck the pen between two fingers on my right hand, so it is always right there.

Answer (score 1):

I love them so much I have 2 on my desk.  You simply can not go wrong, the only time I need/use a mouse is playing games, and I wish I could use the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly dislike a tablet for programming. I even have a tablet laptop I "permanently borrowed" from my girlfriend, and even the idea of using that for any aspect of programming just makes me cringe.

My left hand is always on the keyboard, while my right is jumping to and from the mouse. Because the left is on the keyboard all the time, it is also the most logical hand to perform shortcuts with. Tablets lack the convenience of "quick-switches" due to the pen. Even if you did not have to use the pen, it is unlikely you will be able to achieve the same kind of speed of switching to your tablet, moving slightly, then switching back, as you can with a mouse.

Finally, even if you are as quick with a tablet as you are with a mouse, buttons are in a much less convenient location. Who looks at their mouse when clicking a button? I'd hope nobody. Now, who looks at their tablet? Hmm, I see a lot more hands in the air.

If a tablet suits you, then sure, go for it. But you have to be pretty bad with a mouse to be better with a tablet.

If the reason you want to switch or have switched is due to comfort, either get a new mouse, one of those (often gel-like) wrist rests, or physically reposition yourself. There is a solution to the discomfort, and it's not in the form of a tablet.

Comment: I never have to look at my tablet to click, touch it for left hold it for 1 sec for right.  Not to mention that I don't ever have to pick up my pen and move it left because I am going a large distance, I just touch where I want to be.